# Ошибка в простейшем калькуляторе

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В простом калькуляторе, где я перемножаю два числа у меня выходит ошибка. Я не знаю как можно исправить. Делаю все как в примерах, но ...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView solarCol, solarNumber, solarPrice, solarresult;
EditText solarN, solarP;
Button res;
float num1=0;
float num2=0;
float result=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    solarCol=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.collecTitel);
    solarNumber= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collecNum);
    solarPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collecrPrice);
    solarresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

    solarN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNS);
    solarP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNP);

    res = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    res.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {


    num1=Float.parseFloat(solarN.getText().toString());
    num2=Float.parseFloat(solarP.getText().toString());

    result=num1*num2;
    solarresult.setText(result);
}
```

}

Ругается на переменную **result**  в конце.Просит перевести в Int. Но даже это не помогает. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как именно ругается? И какое "даже это" не помогает?

Comment: result+"", может просит перевести в String?

Comment: Непонятно, где вы увидели, что "просит перевести в Int"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На `setText(result)` программа ищет строковый ресурс с `int id = result`, так как думает, что вы используете `getString(R.string.myString)`

сделайте `setText(String.valueOf(result))` и все заработает